# We would like to find the smallest, 3rd-smallest, 5th-smallest and 7th-smallest of n elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

How can it be done within 3n + o(n) COMPARISONS?

I have tried to take an array of size 7 (a[6]) and the traverse over the given array. Then insert the element in a[] in a sorted order (6log(6) comparisons for each insert after the first 7 and o(6) before that).So total comparisions = n-7(7log(7))+6(6+1)/2 which is greater than what I want. Can someone describe an algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the space constraints?

Comment: None and no time constraints too, but the number of comparisons should be within 3n+o(n).

Comment: By "none" do you mean the algorithm can use any amount of space, or it cannot use any additional space? (i.e. must be in-place / constant-space)?

Comment: What is the time complexity required?

Comment: it can use any amount of space and time.

Comment: Then form a max heap of size 7 and keep on inserting elements in it while traversing the original array. If the element is smaller than max element in heap, remove it and insert that element in the heap else continue.

Answer (score 2):

Let's iterate through the input array `A` and on every iteration maintain sorted array `smallest` containing 7 smallest elements so far:

```
smallest = [INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF, INF]
for each Number in A
    find the insert position of the Number (if any) in the smallest array with binary 
        search (3 comparisons)
    insert to the smallest if needed (0 comparisons)
```

At the end, we have 7 smallest elements and the total number of comparisons is `3*n`.

If we don't have `INF` analogue for the elements we can take first 7 elements and sort them (this sort is `O(1)`), and then iterate through the remaining part of the array. Number of comparisons in this case is equal to `(n-7)*3 + O(1) = 3*n + O(1)`

Comment: I think the initial value for smallest should be arbitrary 7 items(e.g. first 7), since it may need n comparison for finding maxn.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic I mean some kind of infinity, not the maximal number, need to change this name, thanks. And yes, we surely can take the first 7 numbers and sort them in `O(1)`

Comment: How can you sort the first 7 elements in O(1) comparisons?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaNelloore With constant number of elements every sorting algorithm has O(1) complexity because the number of operations does not depend on the size of the input (n in our case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QuickSelect algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). The average running time is O(n).

> - None and no time constraints too, but the number of comparisons should be within 3n+o(n).
> - It can use any amount of space and time.

You also mention that there is no time requirement as long as you meet the number of comparison requirement. There are some sorting algorithm that does zero element comparison. If your data is integer, you can use Radix Sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).